# mislabeled data Event Detection, neural language processing

Tags: natural-language, information-retrieval, labeling

I'm doing some experiment with sequence labeling problems, more specifically is Event detection problem. But I'm encountering with the mislabeled data issue.

In my dataset, there are many tokens that is labeled to 'O' tag( None label), however, my model has predicted it to another tag, I have checked the results, it seems to be correctly classified.

I wonder that these papers that work with Event Detection on the same dataset with me, How they deal with this issue, they relabel all these mislabeled token or keep the original data( and their model are really good)  I have sent a lot of email to the author of these papers that I found, to find some advices, but no one answer me.Have anyone of you encountered with this issue and can give me some advice?

Your answer will be really meaningful to me.